# when strong reference directly access weak reference

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references, strong-references

In Java, when an target object A is only reached by weak reference B, A can be GC.
what happen if the weak reference B is reached by a strong reference C at same time? For exmaple, C points to a class instance which contains a field of weak reference B which points to A.
If C is live, and there is no other weak or strong reference to obj A, can A still be GC?

Comment: The weak reference itself doesn't have to be collectable. Only what it references.

Comment: I understand this, I'd like to know collectability of the target object A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since there is one weak refence as a link it is considered weakly reachable. The Wikipedia entry on [**Weak reference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) says (in part)

> A **weak reference** is a reference that does not protect the referenced object from collection by a garbage collector, unlike a strong reference. An object referenced only by weak references – meaning "every chain of references that reaches the object includes at least one weak reference as a link" – is considered weakly reachable, and can be treated as unreachable and so may be collected at any time.

Comment: we know threadlocal is implemented by using ThreadLocalMap class which contains Entry of weak reference type. each Entry weakly points to a threadlocal variable. If that is the case as said the above article, threadlocal variable can be GC at any time even it is still being used by the thread. any thing I am missing?

Comment: Not if there are strong references in the `ThreadLocal` itself.

Comment: You're very welcome. You might also take a look at [Hans Boehm's Conservative Garbage Collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/); it predates the JVM but is (I think) quite readable.